# How do I subclass two parent classes' inner classes to correctly define an inner class on a child class?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to define an inner class in a hierarchy of classes and I can't figure out the right way to make sure that the inner class correctly subclasses the parents' corresponding inner classes without throwing an exception in the case where one or more of the immediate parent classes has not themselves subclassed that inner class.

I've also tried many times to write this question in a more approachable way, so I apologise if it's a bit of a headscratcher!

Hopefully this example will clarify things:

(assume for this question that we don't know which, if any, of B or C define subclasses of A.Inner - obviously in this example neither do, but that's not the point.)

Cheers.

```py
class A:
    class Inner:
        ...
class B(A):
    ...
class C(A):
    ...
class D(B, C):
    class Inner(B.Inner, C.Inner):
        ...
>>>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-6f592c573c6f> in <module>
      6 class C(A):
      7     ...
----> 8 class D(B, C):
      9     class Inner(B.Inner, C.Inner):
     10         ...

<ipython-input-163-6f592c573c6f> in D()
      7     ...
      8 class D(B, C):
----> 9     class Inner(B.Inner, C.Inner):
     10         ...

TypeError: duplicate base class Inner
```

Comment: Do either of `B` or `C` subclass `A.inner`?

Comment: We're assuming that we don't know whether they do or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that if `A.inner` is a class, and `B` or `C` do not explicitly subclass the inner class, then `B.inner` and `C.inner` are the *same object* -> `A.inner`:

```
>>> class A:
...  class inner: pass
... 
>>> class B(A): pass
... 
>>> class C(A): pass
... 
>>> B.inner is C.inner
True
>>> C.inner is A.inner
True
```

We're leveraging a dictionary to ensure uniqueness *and* order (use `collections.OrderedDict` or some other ordered_set implementation if you are on a version that does not yet guarantee dict order). We can determine which classes we need to subclass on `D.inner` like so:

```
inner_classes = {getattr(klass, 'inner'): True for klass in [C, B]  # control your MRO here.
                 if getattr(klass, 'inner') is not A.inner}
# Ensure that we also extend A.inner, in case neither B nor C subclasses A.inner
inner_classes[A.inner] = True
class D(A):
  class inner(*inner_classes.keys()): pass
```

In this way we get consistent MRO, it doesn't matter which class (if any) subclasses `A.inner`, and `D.inner` works.

Comment: Hmm okay, I think I follow you. It hadn't occurred to me that you could use star notation in that context! Could this work be encapsulated in a class wrapper I wonder? This is an operation I'll be repeating a lot throughout my envisioned class structure.

Answer (score 0):

Alright folks, going on from g.d.d.c's partial answer, I think we have a solution here that works cleanly and simply for arbitrary class hierarchies.

I'll do some testing on it for a couple of days and see if it does the job. I'm still not happy with the requirement to specify the bases manually - I feel like some sort of introspection inside the wrapper could handle this automatically. Please do chime in with more suggestions.

Thanks heaps again to g.d.d.c for kicking me in the right direction!

```py
def inner_class(*bases):
    def _inner_class(cls):
        bs = []
        for b in bases:
            try: bs.append(getattr(b, cls.__name__))
            except AttributeError: pass
        bs = sorted(set(bs), key = bs.index)
        return type(cls)(
            cls.__name__,
            (cls, *bs),
            {}
            )
    return _inner_class

class A:
    class Inner:
        ...
class B(A):
    class Inner(A.Inner):
        ...
class C(A):
    ...
class D(A):
    ...
class E(B, C, D):
    @inner_class(B, C, D)
    class Inner:
        ...

print(E.Inner.mro())

>>> [<class '__main__.Inner'>, <class '__main__.E.Inner'>, <class '__main__.B.Inner'>, <class '__main__.A.Inner'>, <class 'object'>]
```